# What makes Ksav Arizal unacceptable to some?

Tags: sources-mekorot, torah-reading, megillat-esther, aleph-bet-letters, safrus

A certain rabbi said that Megillas Ester written in Ksav Arizal should not be used in nussach Sefard shul because people won't be yotze with its reading. What makes Ksav Arizal so different as to make it's reading unacceptable to some?

Comment: Are you sure he said "nusach Sefard" and not "Sefaradi"?

Comment: @Heshy - yes, I specifically confirmed with him at the time. It's a shul where most people come from nusach Ashkenaz background, but the shul itself uses nussach Sfard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modern "Ari script" has the right head of the Tzadi facing to the right, while modern "Beit Yosef" script has it facing left. Historically, the head has been written facing all sorts of ways (even upwards) even in Ashkenazi lands without qualms.

In the early 20th century, the Chazon Ish famously [allegedly] was concerned that the modern "Ari script" way was invalid, but most rabbis defended the viability of the practice. See R' Aryeh Friedman's book on the topic [Tzidkat Ha-Tzaddik](https://hebrewbooks.org/20944).

Comment: Would this alone prevent someone from being Yotze with reading a megilla written in Ksav Ari?

Comment: @Tesvov if you combine the right opinions, why not? I'm not saying I find the possibility plausible.