# What's the connection between the yod's on the letter tzadik, the faces of Adam and chava, and the kruvim

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, mysticism-kabbalah, aleph-bet-letters, torah-writing, written-torah

I have heard but I cannot find any sources linking these concepts. The [Shulchan Aruch HaRav](https://shulchanaruchharav.com/the-different-styles-of-script-used-in-stam-today-kesav-beis-yosef-arizal-vallish-source-and-background/#_ftn21) mentions that the *yod*'s on the letter *tzadik* are written upside down in *ktav arizal*; basically not facing each other. However, as answered [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/111835/what-makes-ksav-arizal-unacceptable-to-some), the *yod* on the right side of the bent *nun* faces left towards the other *yod* in *ktav beit yosef*. Rabbi Dr. Ari Z. Zivotofsky touches up this in [What’s the Truth about … Adam’s Spare Rib?](https://jewishaction.com/religion/jewish-thought/whats_the_truth_about_adams_spare_rib/), but doesn't make the connection with the *kruvim*. It seems obvious, but I can't find any sources linking the lot of these. What does it mean when they are facing *vis-à-vis* opposing?

Comment: "bent nun". Do you mean tzadi? Not sure what you mean by nun here. The left half of the tzadi?

Comment: Also, I couldn't find what you considered relevant in the article by R' Zivotofsky.

Comment: The bent nun is how Rabbi Ginsburgh, Rabbi Aaron L. Raskin, and Rav Pinson describe the tzadik. Two yud's on a bent nun.

Comment: According to the Zohar, the two top “yuds” that make up the Hebrew letter tzaddi represent this “double-faced” creature originally created by God. Sources debate whether the two beings faced the same direction or opposite directions; this argument forms the basis of the debate between Rabbi Yosef Karo and the Arizal regarding how to properly write a tzaddi.

Comment: This is a really interesting source from RH Schechter; I wonder if you have a quote of it since it's hard for me to find it. Or even, a direct link to the Zohar that talks about the letter tzaddi. The above article gives a bunch of sources, mostly about Adam and Chavah, and it wasn't easy to find what I wanted.

Comment: It is pretty unique, true? Are there any other letters at all that face right?

Comment: The only sources I can find are Zohar III, p. 180b; Sefer HaArachim Chabad, Osios, letter tzaddik, p. 315. I'm unsure if they're online but I will take a look.

Comment: https://www.mezuzamehudar.com/res_what_you_should_know.php

Comment: Just looking at the different letters, the tzaddik and the chet stand out the most. However, it appears that the rest of the letters have one yod looking in and one looking out.